# hiredis rebuild with .net framework 2.0 error

Tags: npm-install, hiredis

I tried remove and install the related files for .net framework 3.5 (include the 2.0). [Suggested in this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51557850/target-net-framework-2-0-not-net-core-2-0-with-visual-studio-2017)

Tried to install visual studio 2005 as suggested in the second thing that was suggested in the error.

I cannot find hiredis folder under node_modules.

Other thing I tried to clean my cache and delete node_modules and reinstall again as suggested in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532854/error-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-visual-studio-2017-buildtools-msbuild-1?rq=1).

```
MSBUILD : 
error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 
1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 
2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 
3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  
[D:\path\src\node_modules\hiredis\build\binding.sln]
```

The full error find in the image.

[image: Hiredis Error]

Answer (score 0):

This apparently is a common error people come across as a window user.

If you are recently update your Visual studio to a new version such as 2012 and above will see similar from the above.

There are articurs on this, if you use the right search keys, here is one of them and the author explains it in details. [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562386/Lessons-learned-migrating-to-Visual-Studio-2012-an)

three solutions:

1) npm install -g windows-build-tools [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658832/npm-install-error-msb3428-could-not-load-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-ex)

2) install visual studio 10 -> npm clear cache --force -> delete node_modules/ -> delete package-lock.js npm config set msvs_version 2010 -g

3) manually download the neccaries files then npm config set msvs_version  -g [github](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2074)